# How to get the navigation drawer below the action bar, not below of the tab bar

Tags: tabs

I am getting my navigation drawer below the tab bar but I want it to be below the title bar or action bar.

The second problem is when Navigation drawer is opened, even if we click on the tabs it is changing fragments. I want tabs click should be disable, when Navigation drawer is opened

Here is my main_layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:contextClickable="false"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have tried placing viewpager element above the drawerlayout even though I am getting same problem.

Here is my emulator output screenshot 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use drawer layout over action bar as usual but insert `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` line to `drawerLayout` tag... Or move `tabLayout` tag to below `navigationView` tag